# Why does Tkinter getvar() return string types for Booleanvar?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter offers the BooleanVar type for booleans stored in its widgets.
However, using the getvar method on a named BooleanVar returns a string type. This does not make sense to me as a BooleanVar getter should return a boolean.

Any insight into why Tkinter is made this way?

Here is a brief example code that shows what happens:

```
# importing tkinter module 
from tkinter import *
  
# creating Tk() variable 
master = Tk() 
  
# Tkinter variables 
boolvar = BooleanVar(master, name ="bool") 
Checkbutton(master, 
            text="check", 
            variable=boolvar,
            command=lambda: printvar()).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
  
# Setting values of variables 
master.setvar(name ="bool", value = False)
  
# getting values of each variables using getvar() method
def printvar():
    print("Value of BooleanVar()", master.getvar(name ="bool"))
    print("Type of BooleanVar()", type(master.getvar(name ="bool")))
mainloop()
```

Which create a window with a checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked, this output is printer to the terminal:

```
Value of BooleanVar() 1
Type of BooleanVar() <class 'str'>
Value of BooleanVar() 0
Type of BooleanVar() <class 'str'>
Value of BooleanVar() 1
Type of BooleanVar() <class 'str'>
Value of BooleanVar() 0
Type of BooleanVar() <class 'str'>
```

Of course I can solve this by parsing the string, but this does not seem like an elegant way for an included Python library to behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few interesting things happening here.

First, the embedded Tcl interpreter that is the foundation of Tkinter has no concept of boolean values. It uses the value `0` to represent false and any other number to represent true. `BoolVar` handles that in its `get` method by converting whatever the internal Tcl variable holds to either `True` or `False`.

However, you aren't calling the `get` method of the variable. Instead, you are calling `getvar` which returns the raw, unconverted value stored in the tcl interpreter.

Further compounding the problem, you aren't properly configuring the `Checkbutton`. Because you don't define the `onvalue` and `offvalue` options they default to the strings "1" and "0".

If you properly set the `onvalue` and `offvalue` to `True` and `False`, and call the `get` method of the variable rather than using `getvar`, you'll get back a proper boolean value.

Or, if you want to use `getvar`, you should do what `BoolVar` does and convert the value to a boolean using the internal tkinter function `getboolean`.

```
Checkbutton(..., onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
...
def printvar():
    ...
    value = master.tk.getboolean(master.getvar(name="bool"))
    print(f"value: {value} type of value: {type(value)}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation - pretty interesting to me that checkboxes default to string values, but it makes sense with the rest of your explanation.

Comment: @shimmer_flight: underlying tkinter is a tcl interpreter. The entire language is based on strings. While it of course supports numbers, it's mantra is "everything is a string". When you understand the Tcl language, it's not strange at all that it defaults to a string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value you can use the variable itself rather than getting the `master` instance value.

```
# importing tkinter module 
from tkinter import *
  
# creating Tk() variable 
master = Tk() 
  
# Tkinter variables 
boolvar = BooleanVar(master, name ="bool") 
x = Checkbutton(master, 
            text="check", 
            variable=boolvar,
            command=lambda: printvar()).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
  
# Setting values of variables 
master.setvar(name ="bool", value = False)
  
# getting values of each variables using get() method
def printvar():
    print("Value of BooleanVar()", boolvar.get())
    print("Type of BooleanVar()", type(boolvar.get()))
mainloop()
```

Output:

```
Value of BooleanVar() True
Type of BooleanVar() <class 'bool'>
Value of BooleanVar() False
Type of BooleanVar() <class 'bool'>
```

Thus it shows the type of the variable as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a methodology that works for me:

```
import tkinter as tk
 
 
class ROOT(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screenName=None, baseName=None, className="Tk", useTk=True, sync=False, use=None)
        self.vars = {}
        self._var_types = {
            str: tk.StringVar,
            int: tk.IntVar,
            float: tk.DoubleVar,
            bool: tk.BooleanVar
        }
        self._create_var(name=None)

    def getvar(self, name: str):
        return self.vars[name].get()

    def setvar(self, name: str, value):
        name = self._create_var(name=name, value=value)
        if value:
            self.vars[name].set(value)
    
    def _create_var(self, name: str = None, value = None):
        if name not in self.vars:
            var_type = self._var_types[str]
            if value:
                var_type = self._var_types[type(value)]
            var = var_type(name=name, value=value)
            self.vars.update({var._name: var})
            return var._name
        return name
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
root = ROOT()
root.setvar(None, None)
# to create an empty StringVar
# or
root.setvar("apple", 5)
# to create a var with a name and set its value.
# and to get the value:
var_val = root.getvar("apple")
print(f"{"apple is {var_val} with type {type(var_val)}")
```

Out

```
apple is 5 with type <class 'int'>
```

The worst part is you'll need to find a way to propagate this functionality to each widget you want to store variables in. Alternatively, you could just store all your variables in a single location, which usually makes them easier to access.